# How to reference specific HTML files to specific arrays in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file (https://github.com/conde-nast-international/cnid-tech-tests/blob/master/data/article.json) that contains array data about magazine articles (title, body, cover image etc.

I made a HTML page that lists all title's and cover images (see image below)

[image]

I want each article, when clicked on, to redirect to another HTML document that I have made (using the same JSON data) that displays more detail about the article (see image below)

[image]

The issue is, all I have currently is an index.html file and several other article HTML files (article-one.html, article-two.html, article-three.html etc.) for each individual article array. Is there a way I can reference each article JSON array to the corresponding HTML file? Apologies if this seems a bit confusing, I've spent days trying to figure out how to do this with no luck so all suggestions are extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Index.html:

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/cn-header.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Article-one.html:

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="images/cn-header.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

JavaScript (for index.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<div class="article"> <a href=" '+ /*somehow must link to other HTML pages I've created*/ +' ">';
      article_data += '<div class="title-home">' + value.title + '</div>';
      article_data += '<div class="cover-home"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';
      article_data += '</a> </div>';
    });
    $('#container').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

JavaScript (for article-one.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<div class="a-body">';
      article_data += '<div class="page-left">';
      article_data += '<div class="page-title">' + value.title + '</div>';
      article_data += '<div class="page-cover"> <img src="' + value.cover + '"> </div>';
      article_data += '</div>';
      article_data += '<div class="page-right">';
      article_data += '<div class="page-body">';
      $.each(value.body, function (index, el) {
         if (el.type == 'plaintext') {
           article_data += '<div class="plaintext">' + el.body + '</div>';
         } else if (el.type == 'h2') {
           article_data += '<div class="h2">' + el.body + '</div>';
         } else if (el.type == 'pull_quote') {
           article_data += '<div class="pull_quote">' + el.body + '</div>';
         }
      });
      article_data += '</div>';
      article_data += '</div>';
      article_data += '</div>';
    });
    $('#container').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a field named `article` to your json object where you can save the link to be opened when the user clicks on your card.

## Javasript

```
var data = [
 {id: 1, article: 'article-one.html', title: 'First Lorem ipsum', image: 'path/img/1'},
 {id: 2, article: 'article-two.html', title: 'Second Lorem ipsum', image: 'path/img/2'}
];

var store= '';

$(document).ready(function(){
   data.forEach(function(item, index){
       store = store+'
          <div id="'+item.id+'"class="card">
            <a href="'+item.article+'">
               <h1>'+item.title+'</h1>
               <div class="body">
                  <img src="'item.image'">
               </div>
             </a>
          </div>
       ';
   });

   $('.cards').html(store);

});
```

## html

```
<div class="cards">
   <!-- your cards will be loaded here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work (and I don't really understand it to be honest) :S

Comment: have you been using jQuery for long?

Comment: Not very much unfortunately, but I've added the HTML & JavaScript, would you mind looking at that for a bit more context?

Comment: what you need to do is to get the the url to the article from the json file

Comment: Do you mean I must parse the article-one.html file to the JSON file and call that's article file using + value.article + ?

Comment: you don't parse the article-one-html file to the JSON first but you add it to your file json object as a string like this `'article-one-html'`. so that when you are retrieving the json data, you can know to which article does an object belongs.

Comment: OK, so from what I understand, to the JSON file I have added "page":"article-one.html" to the end of the first article array, and added article_data += '<div class="article"> <a href=" '+ value.page +' ">'; to the HTML, but when clicked, the error of 'undefined' occurs.. is this wrong?

Comment: don't put the the key in quotes, just put is like this: `page: "article-one.html"` and make sure that the article-one.html is in the same folder as index.html